# Let $B = {n \in \mathbb{Z} : n = 3j + 2; j \in \mathbb{Z}}, D = {n \in Z : n = 3j − 1; j \in \mathbb{Z}}$. Is $B = D$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $B = {n \in \mathbb{Z} : n = 3j + 2; j \in \mathbb{Z}}, D = {n \in Z : n = 3j − 1; j \in \mathbb{Z}}$. Is $B = D$?

How do I prove this?

To me it looks to be true. But I don't know how to put it to words.

I have a doubt on this. Here the "$j$" they are referring to is different for both sets right? Or are they referring to the same "$j$"?

Comment: Why does it "look to be true"? If you cannot convince yourself, you cannot hope to have a proof. If you can convince yourself, then you certainly can explain in English why you are convinced.

Comment: With your edit, you're now asking what the notation means. If you don't know the set notation, then how can it "look to be true"??

Comment: LOL. Im laughing at my self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$B = \{n ∈ Z : n = 3j + 2; j ∈ \mathbb{Z}\}, D = \{n ∈ Z : n = 3j − 1; j ∈ \mathbb{Z}\}$.

In $D$,
$$\{n ∈ Z : n=3j-1, j ∈ \mathbb{Z}\}$$
can be written as
$$\{n ∈ Z : n=3(j-1)+2, j-1 ∈ \mathbb{Z}\}$$
Let $j-1=k$, thus
$$\{n ∈ Z : n=3k+2, k ∈ \mathbb{Z}\}$$
which is nothing but the set $B$.

Comment: You can produce $\mathbb{Z}$ by typing \mathbb{Z} when you are in math mode.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks! I am new to MathJax, will keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Any free variables (not bound by quantifiers) in the set notation range over all possible values. So what "$j$" means in one set definition has nothing to do with what it means in another. Same for $n$, which is also a free variable. $B$ is the set of all integers that are $2$ more than three times some integer. $D$ is the set of all integers that are $1$ less than three times some integer. Are they clearly the same? Can you see that each element in $B$ is also in $D$ and vice versa?